Examples of Convex (But Not Strongly Convex), L-smooth functions
The question is in the title. I am looking for functions or families of functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that are both convex and $L$-smooth for some $L>0$, but not strongly convex, I know that $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $f(x)=\log(1+e^{-bx})$ are two examples. Can you give me some more? I am trying test out a claim and could really use some more examples.

Why quadratic one is not strongly convex?

Probably trivial but any linear function. Also, the quadratic is strongly convex if $a \neq 0$.
